# Footer behind content BUT set px automatically

Tags: html, css, footer, slideup

This is what I want: jsfiddle.net/zVLrb/
from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095684/footer-behind-content)
But I do it by bootstrap, so I don't know-want to set the height as for example 200px but recognize aytomatically

Thank for the answers...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but you need some JavaScript.
Make a function (`.accomodateFooter()` in the example below) that gets the `height` of the footer and sets it as `padding-bottom` for the `<body>` (or whatever page wrapper with `position:relative` your layout might have - usually the direct parent of the `footer`), so your page contents do not get covered by the footer.
You will need to run this function on page `load` & `resize` events and also on footer `DOMSubtreeModified`.

Proof of concept:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.accomodateFooter = function(){
    var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
    $(this).css({'padding-bottom':footerHeight+'px'});
  }
  // adjust footer after it's html was modified
  $('footer').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    $('body').accomodateFooter();
  })
  // adjust footer when page loaded or resized. ideally, debounced.
  $(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('body').accomodateFooter();
  })
  $('body').accomodateFooter();
  window.feedFooter = function() {
    var f = $('footer');
    f.append($('<p />',{
      text:"Human give me attention meow flop over sun bathe licks your face wake up wander around the house making large amounts of noise jump on top of your human's bed and fall asleep again. Throwup on your pillow sun bathe. The dog smells bad jump around on couch, meow constantly until given food, so nap all day, yet hiss at vacuum cleaner."}))
    .append($('<hr />'));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 54px;
}
footer {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.65);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
}
footer hr {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.42);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.21);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Feed the footer - not a game (yet!)</h1>
        <p class="lead">You will notice the body bottom padding is growing to accomodate the height of the footer as you feed it (so the page contents do not get covered by it).</p><hr /><button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.feedFooter()">Feed that footer</button><hr /><blockquote class="lead"><strong>Note:</strong> I used jQuery <code>v3.0.0</code> and Bootstrap <code>v4-alpha</code> but this is only a proof of concept. It will work on any version of Bootstrap. Cheers!</blockquote>
      </div>

    </div>
<footer>I am a footer with dynamic content.
  <hr />
```